# "Template:!" output from imported MediaWiki template (Infobox)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I am quite new to Mediawiki and am trying to get infoboxes work.

I managed to get a simple one working but am now trying to get the 'Infobox video game' one working.

I am getting the following errors:

```
Template:!- style="" Template:! Developer(s) || Peter Harrap, Shaun     Hollingworth Template:!- style="background: #F0F0F0;" Template:! Publisher(s) || Gremlin Graphics
```

The page is [www.retroresource.co.uk/mediawiki](http://www.retroresource.co.uk/mediawiki)

To try and solve this myself I have been to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export

and entered in:

Template:Infobox

and

Template:Infobox video game

into the box, ticked all boxes, done a find a replace on replace text/plain with CONTENT_FORMAT_TEXT

I have imported the file through special imports.

I have also copied in the default CSS MediaWiki:Common.css into my own wiki.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Template:!`. MediaWiki 1.24 removed the need for that template, but [you are still on version 1.23](http://retroresource.co.uk/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special:Version)

You can either update your wiki to 1.24 or add this in `Template:!`:

```
<onlyinclude>|</onlyinclude>
```

Comment: I have edited my post as I am now getting 'Lua error: Internal error: The interpreter exited with status 2.'

Comment: That seems to be an [different issue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto#Lua_error:_Internal_error:_The_interpreter_exited_with_status_2). I see a clean infobox on your Main Page now.

Comment: Hello, yes sorry. You are right.  Your fix worked thank you.  I will start a fresh thread for this new installation.

Comment: Alright, good luck with the other issue. If you feel this question is properly answered, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer, it's up to you. (Also applies to your other questions btw).